Interrupt protection in ESP32 from interference signals
When my ESP32 is powered with an external 5V adapter or 12V power (2596 DC-DC to 5V), and my water meter (reed switch) is connected with the ESP32, the pulse start running wild and keeps increasing at each interval (of the debounce delay).
When I connect thd ESP32 to my laptop's USB port, there are no random pulses on the ESP32 with the reed switch wires connected.
I'm reading 4 pulses, storing those counter in EEPROM, using interrupt on GPIO 25, 26, 27 and 35.
Code:
#include <EEPROM.h>
#define PULSE_ADDRESS 200

#define pin35  35
#define pin25  25
#define pin26  26
#define pin27  27

const int Pulse1 = pin25;
const int Pulse2 = pin26;
const int Pulse3 = pin27;
const int Pulse4 = pin35;

int PulseHit = 1;
const int debounceDelay = 5000;  // Adjust this value based on your requirements

volatile unsigned long lastDebounceTimePulse1 = 0;
volatile unsigned long lastDebounceTimePulse2 = 0;
volatile unsigned long lastDebounceTimePulse3 = 0;
volatile unsigned long lastDebounceTimePulse4 = 0;

volatile unsigned long pulse1Count = 0;
volatile unsigned long pulse2Count = 0;
volatile unsigned long pulse3Count = 0;
volatile unsigned long pulse4Count = 0;

void IRAM_ATTR handlePulse1() {
  if ((millis() - lastDebounceTimePulse1) > debounceDelay) {
    PulseHit = 1;
    lastDebounceTimePulse1 = millis();
    pulse1Count++;
  }
}

void IRAM_ATTR handlePulse2() {
  if ((millis() - lastDebounceTimePulse2) > debounceDelay) {
    PulseHit = 1;
    lastDebounceTimePulse2 = millis();
    pulse2Count++;
  }
}

void IRAM_ATTR handlePulse3() {
  if ((millis() - lastDebounceTimePulse3) > debounceDelay) {
    PulseHit = 1;
    lastDebounceTimePulse3 = millis();

    pulse3Count++;
  }
}

void IRAM_ATTR handlePulse4() {
  if ((millis() - lastDebounceTimePulse4) > debounceDelay) {
    PulseHit = 1;
    lastDebounceTimePulse4 = millis();
    pulse4Count++;
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(Pulse1, INPUT);
  pinMode(Pulse2, INPUT);
  pinMode(Pulse3, INPUT);
  pinMode(Pulse4, INPUT);

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(Pulse1), handlePulse1, RISING);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(Pulse2), handlePulse2, RISING);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(Pulse3), handlePulse3, RISING);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(Pulse4), handlePulse4, RISING);

  lastDebounceTimePulse1 = millis();
  lastDebounceTimePulse2 = millis();
  lastDebounceTimePulse3 = millis();
  lastDebounceTimePulse4 = millis();

  EEPROM.begin(512);
  EEPROM.get(PULSE_ADDRESS, pulse1Count);
  EEPROM.get(PULSE_ADDRESS + sizeof(pulse1Count), pulse2Count);
  EEPROM.get(PULSE_ADDRESS + 2 * sizeof(pulse1Count), pulse3Count);
  EEPROM.get(PULSE_ADDRESS + 3 * sizeof(pulse1Count), pulse4Count);
  EEPROM.end();
}

void loop() {
  // Print the results
  if (PulseHit == 1) {
    Serial.print("RISING Pulse on pin 25: ");
    Serial.println(pulse1Count);

    Serial.print("RISING Pulse on pin 26: ");
    Serial.println(pulse2Count);

    Serial.print("RISING Pulse on pin 27: ");
    Serial.println(pulse3Count);

    Serial.print("RISING Pulse on pin 35: ");
    Serial.println(pulse4Count);

    Serial.println(" ");

    PulseHit = 0;

    // Save pulse counts to EEPROM
    EEPROM.begin(512);
    EEPROM.put(PULSE_ADDRESS, pulse1Count);
    EEPROM.put(PULSE_ADDRESS + sizeof(pulse1Count), pulse2Count);
    EEPROM.put(PULSE_ADDRESS + 2 * sizeof(pulse1Count), pulse3Count);
    EEPROM.put(PULSE_ADDRESS + 3 * sizeof(pulse1Count), pulse4Count);
    EEPROM.commit();
    EEPROM.end();
  }
}

I have gone through the similar questions below; I haven't tried the capacitor, but I added a debounce of 2 seconds in the code which should be enough, but if not, please let me know.
I have tried 1k, 10k, and 330 resistors to PULL-UP as well as PULL-DOWN.

How to avoid electromagnetic interference on ESP32 input
https://forum.arduino.cc/t/pulse-counting-with-an-external-device/316432/11
https://forum.arduino.cc/t/rain-gauge-reed-switch-interference/466087/6
https://forum.arduino.cc/t/interrupt-problems-on-arduino/496335/11
Measure revolutions per second with reed switch

Are there any other ways to suppress the interferences on thd ESP32?
Edited:
void setup() {
  for (int i = 0; i < numleds; i++) {
    pinMode(ledPins[i], OUTPUT);
  }

  pinMode(Pulse1, INPUT);
  pinMode(Pulse2, INPUT);
  pinMode(Pulse3, INPUT);
  pinMode(Pulse4, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
if (digitalRead(Pulse1) == HIGH) {
  digitalWrite(ledPins[0], HIGH);
} else {
  digitalWrite(ledPins[0], LOW);
}


start at the begining ... write simple code that turns on an LED when the switch is closed and turns off the LED when the switch is open ... please report back with the frequency with which the LED cycles

@jsotola without any delay? on turning on and off

what would be the reason to use a delay? ... just have the LED show the state of the switch ... that way you can tell how often the switch gets activated

do you have access to an oscilloscope?

The issue happens onsite, can't hook the oscilloscope there. But I will try the LED on/off.

@jsotola Okay the led is blinking way too fast, can only notice in dark.
added test code in original question

blinking too fast ... what does that mean? ... blinking too often? ... of turns off too quickly? ... BTW, all you need is one program line digitalWrite(ledPins[0], digitalRead(Pulse1));

Yes, turn on and off so quickly that, barely see it turning on.

run less water through the water meter ... see if the pulse repeats at a slower rate

The meter was not running at all, it was taking EMI from a nearby meter which is powered on AC and also a router module.
I tried with 220 Ohm Pull-up resistor it seems to improve the EMi impression to some extent.
